# How to ensure that some code runs on same background thread with runloop

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, realm, nsrunloop

I am using realm in an iOS app.

I am calling realm methods in a background thread. Realm objects can be used only in the thread where it was created.

This means that I have to ensure that all the code related to accessing realm objects happen on the same thread. This question has been answered here - [How to ensure to run some code on same background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49043257/how-to-ensure-to-run-some-code-on-same-background-thread)

The background thread has no runloop and hence realm objects do not get refreshed automatically.

Can any one point out how to create a background thread with a runloop so that the code blocks can be executed on the same background thread with runloop?

Comment: Why not just use `realm.refresh()`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce The realm db can get updated in other threads. So, even if I call realm.refresh(), I may not calling it frequently enough to get the latest changes to realm

Comment: Ah. In that case you really do need a runloop, if you need to run on every change. Unfortunately i don't know enough about Swift stuff to tell you how to open your own "looper thread" on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing more about your use case (or Realm for that matter!) a suggestion - do you need to use a background thread at all?

Seems that some suggest the Main UI Thread is fine most of the time and may simplify your life.

[Is it acceptable to load Realm objects in the main ui thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39184327/is-it-acceptable-to-load-realm-objects-in-the-main-ui-thread)

Comment: I think I need to use background thread because I am performing some processing using the realm that is not related to UI